# Proper way to use OnFailure in systemd

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I have a service running software that generates some configuration files if they don't exist, and read them if they do exist. The problem I have been facing is that these files sometimes get corrupt, making the software unable to start, and thus making the service fail. In this case I would like to remove these files and restart the service.

I tried creating a service that should get executed in case of failure, by doing this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/run_program
OnFailure=software-fail.service
```

where this service is:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/rm /file/to/delete
ExecStop=systemctl --user start software.service
```

The problem, however, is that this service doesn't start, even when the service has failed.
I tried doing

```
systemctl --user enable software-fail.service
```

but then it starts every time the system starts, just like any other service.

My temporary solution is to use

```
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /file/to/delete
```

but this is not a satisfying way of solving it, as it will always delete the file upon stopping the service, no matter if it was because of failure or not.

Output when failing:

```
● software.service - Software
   Loaded: loaded (/home/trippelganger/.config/systemd/user/software.service; enabled;  vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-05-04 09:05:26 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 1839 ExecStart=/bin/run_program (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1839 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)



May 04 09:05:26 trippelganger systemd[595]: software.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 09:05:26 trippelganger systemd[595]: software.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 04 09:05:26 trippelganger systemd[595]: software.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Output of systemctl --user status software-fail.service
is:

```
● software-fail.service - Delete corrupt files
   Loaded: loaded (/home/trippelganger/.config/systemd/user/software-fail.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: @trippelganger Please edit your question to make some corrections. `start_if_fail.service` should probably be `software-fail.service` (from your later systemctl status output) and `ExecStop=systemctl ...` fails because the path is not absolute, so I imagine what you really have is `ExecStop=/bin/systemctl ...` (though it's possible this might also be part of the problem you're having.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**NOTE**: You probably want to use `ExecStopPost=` instead of `OnFailure=` here (see my other answer), but this is trying to address why your `OnFailure=` setup is not working.

The problem with `OnFailure=` not starting the unit might be because it's in the wrong section, it needs to be in the `[Unit]` section and not `[Service]`.

You can try this instead:

```
# software.service
[Unit]
Description=Software
OnFailure=software-fail.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/run_program
```

And:

```
# software-fail.service
[Unit]
Description=Delete corrupt files

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/rm /file/to/delete
ExecStop=/bin/systemctl --user start software.service
```

I can make it work with this setup.

But note that using `OnFailure=` is not ideal here, since you can't really tell why the program failed, and chaining another start of it in `ExecStop=` by calling `/bin/systemctl start` directly is pretty hacky... The solution using `ExecStopPost=` and looking at the exit status is definitely superior.

If you define `OnFailure=` inside `[Service]`, systemd (at least version 234 from Fedora 27) complains with:

```
software.service:6: Unknown lvalue 'OnFailure' in section 'Service'
```

Not sure if you're seeing that in your logs or not... (Maybe this was added in recent systemd?) That should be a hint of what is going on there.

Comment: Thank you, what a stupid mistake! I did not see the "Unknown lvalue" text in my logs, using the latest systemd in Debian Stretch.

Answer (score 13):

In order to perform some cleanup if the service fails, you can use [`ExecStopPost=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=), which is executed whether the service succeeds or not.

In the code you run at `ExecStopPost=`, you can use one of `$SERVICE_RESULT`, `$EXIT_CODE` or `$EXIT_STATUS` to determine the failure condition and act accordingly. See the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#%24SERVICE_RESULT) on those environment variables to check which one is appropriate for you.

Then you can use `Restart=on-failure` so that systemd tries to restart your unit when it fails.

Putting it all together, this is what it would look like. Assuming that `run_program` will exit with status 2 whenever the files are corrupted (hopefully you can adapt this to other failure scenarios from the documentation above), this should work:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/run_program
ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c 'if [ "$$EXIT_STATUS" = 2 ]; then rm /file/to/delete; fi'
Restart=on-failure
```

(*NOTE*: The double dollar-sign `$$` is to escape this to systemd, so the shell sees `$EXIT_STATUS` and accesses that variable. Using a single dollar-sign would also work, but then systemd would do that replacement instead and the shell would see `[ "2" = 2 ]`, which arguably also works... Anyways, you can bypass most of that by putting all this logic into a shell script and calling it by its full path in `ExecStopPost=`, that would be probably better and you could also easily add more commands to the script, such as logging the action taken to recover from the error condition.)

Hopefully this will give you enough pointers to figure out how to configure this correctly given your particular situation!

Comment: Thank you, this is a better way of doing my current solution. However, it does not explain how to properly use the OnFailure command in systemd, which was my original question. I find the systemd documentation can be a bit hard to interpret at times. Also, shouldn't I check for exit status 1, rather than 2?

Comment: Checking exit status 2 was an example, in case your program does something specific in case of file corruption (some programs use different exit status to signal specific conditions.) A more general solution would be checking for `"$$EXIT_STATUS" != 0`, but the best is for you to look at your program's documentation (or source code) and look at the three variables systemd uses and try to figure out what's the best way to detect the error condition in your specific case.

Comment: Indeed I did not explain why `OnFailure=` was not working for you, I focused on the problem you were trying to solve and I think `OnFailure=` is not the best solution for that... I added another answer to address `OnFailure=`, it seems the problem is you have it in the wrong section (`[Service]`, while it should be in `[Unit]`), I hope that's helpful to you as well. In any case, for this specific problem you described, `ExecStopPost=` and checking for exit status (or service result, etc.) is probably a better approach.

Comment: Isn't this kind of situation exactly what OnFailure is used for?

Comment: @filbranden Thank you for this answer. I followed what you have written here but in my system value of all environmental variables were empty. I checked systemd document and found that these environmental variables got introduced with v232 but I am on v219 so cannot use this facility. I also want to run an external script on failure and I have used `ExecStopPost=`. I don't want to run the script on every stop. I want it to run on specific failure (in my case exit status will be `18`). Can you please help me how can I achieve this without having environmental variables facility.

Comment: @vivek systemd v219 is ~10 years old and RHEL/CentOS 7 (which is the version that shipped it, so I assume is what you use) is already at End-of-Life. I definitey recommend upgrading to a newer version, such as RHEL/CentOS 8 which is widely available and has been around for longer than a year (so it's definitely stable.)

Comment: @filbranden Thank you for response. I checked but unfortunately I don't have access to upgrade the systemd version. What I have is systemd version 219 and I have to work with that only.
 I was checking the systemd documentation and found `Onfailure=` option in systemd but with that I guess it will create a new service which I don't want. Also I don't want to run the script every time on failure. I want to run it on specific exit status (in my case it is 18). Can you please guide me how can I achieve this with systemd v219.

Answer (score 2):

Something to be wary of is the `systemd` version.  The goodness of `$EXIT_STATUS` and associated values was introduced with systemd Version 232, released in May 2017

Some Distros (at the time of typing) like RHEL 7.x are still using systemd version 219 which does not set the variables like `$EXIT_STATUS`. Hence you cannot use the excellent advise above :( ...